# parse xml using xpath and get nested childs

Tags: java, xml, xpath

So, I have an XML structure that looks like this.

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actorUID>1w2e3r</actorUID>
        <actor id="1">
            <name>Christian Bale</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </actor>
        <actor id="2">
            <name>LiamNeeson</name>
            <age>45</age>
        </actor>
        <actor id="3">
            <name>Michael</name>
            <age>60</age>
        </actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">
            <name>Michael</name>
            <age>60</age>
        </foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">
            <name>Michael</name>
            <age>60</age>
        </foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">
            <name>Michael</name>
            <age>60</age>
        </foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
</root>
```

I need to parse this json and save the elements of actorUID, actor.name, actor.age, foo:singers.name, foo:singers.age to database.

I have tried this:

```
try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(stops));
                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
                XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/root/actors");
                NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("actorsUID")
                            .item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
                    System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("actor")
                            .item(0)
                            .getTextContent());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How can I get actor name after I got this - `element.getElementsByTagName("actor")`
?

I do not want to just get the name element, as in further if I have to another children to actors, and if it would have actress.name, then it would break.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would suggest implementing a SAX parser. But if you want to use the xpath, two things to note :

- The DocumentBuilderFactory has to be aware of namespace
- xpath has to use a NamespaceContext.

You could set them like:

```
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext ns = new javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext()
{

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) 
    {
        if ( "foo".equals( prefix ) )
        {
            return "http://www.foo.org/";
        }
        else if ( "bar".equals( prefix ) )
        {
            return "http://www.bar.org/";
        }
        else if ( "xml".equals( prefix ) )
        {
            return javax.xml.XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
        }

        return javax.xml.XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;

    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<?> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        return null;
    }

};

xpath.setNamespaceContext(ns);
```

Then for getting the `name`, `age`, or any other child, you could use below code , basically you get child nodes of `actor` and print nodeName, text.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
{
     Element element = (Element) nl.item(i);
     NodeList uids = element.getElementsByTagName("actorUID");
     for ( int j = 0; j < uids.getLength(); j++ )
     {
        System.out.println( "Actor UID : " + uids.item(j).getTextContent());
     }
     NodeList actors = element.getElementsByTagName("actor");
     for ( int j = 0; j < actors.getLength(); j++ )
     {
        NodeList cNodes = actors.item(j).getChildNodes();
        for ( int k = 0; k < cNodes.getLength(); k++ )
        {
            Node node = cNodes.item(k);
            if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE )
            {
                System.out.println( cNodes.item(k).getNodeName() + " : " + cNodes.item(k).getTextContent() );
            }

        }
     }
}
```